# java guava multimap output in particular format

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I have the below MultiMap:

```
Multimap<String, Integer> mm = ArrayListMultimap.create();

mm.put("A", 10);
mm.put("B", 0);
mm.put("C", 0);
mm.put("A", 0);
mm.put("B", 11);
mm.put("C", 0);         
mm.put("A", 0);
mm.put("B", 0);             
mm.put("C", 5);     
mm.put("A", 4);
mm.put("B", 0);
mm.put("C", 0);     
mm.put("A", 0);
mm.put("B", 6);
mm.put("C", 0);     
mm.put("A", 0);
mm.put("B", 0);             
mm.put("C", 8);     
mm.put("A", 2);
mm.put("B", 0);
mm.put("C", 0);     
mm.put("A", 0);
mm.put("B", 0);
mm.put("C", 0);     
mm.put("A", 0);
mm.put("B", 0);             
mm.put("C", 7);

Set<String> keys = mm.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {           
    System.out.println("Key = " + key);
        System.out.println("Values = " + mm.get(key));          
}
```

I get the following output:

> Key = A
>   Values = [10, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
>   Key = B
>   Values = [0, 11, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>   Key = C
>   Values = [0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7]

But I need the output in the format:

> Key = A
>   Values = [10, 4, 2]
>   Key = B
>   Values = [11, 6, 0]
>   Key = C
>   Values = [5, 8, 7]

Comment: Write your own function. There are obviously some rules here, since you've kept a 0 for B's values.

Comment: Can you describe further why you need such output?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `HashMultimap` instead of `ArrayListMultimap`

```
Multimap<String, Integer> mm = HashMultimap.create();
```

Or if `HashMultimap` is not enough for you, you can check the value before putting it into the multimap.

```
if(!mm.containsValue(10)){
    mm.put("A", 10);
}
```

Comment: `HashMultimap` will not work, as it will not not allow duplicates, it also possible to have
Key = A
Values = [10, 4, 4]

Comment: Ok, I added a second part to my answer. Maybe this hint help you a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case could be solved easier with a `Multiset`, not a `Multimap`. First write a helper method:

```
static <T> void  addNTimes(Multiset<T> multiset, T item, int n) {
    multiset.addAll(Collections.nCopies(item, n));
}
```

Now you can rewrite your code:

```
Multiset<String> mm = HashMultiset.create();

addNTimes(mm, "A", 10);
addNTimes(mm, "B", 0);
addNTimes(mm, "C", 0);
addNTimes(mm, "A", 0);
addNTimes(mm, "B", 11);
addNTimes(mm, "C", 0);


Set<Entry<String>> keys = mm.entrySet();
for (Entry<String> entry : keys) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getElement());
    System.out.println("Values = " + entry.getCount());
}
```